# Chibi Scheme - Simple define-library example not working

Tags: scheme, chibi-scheme, r7rs

I wrote the following example, in an attempt to experiment with R7RS libraries in Chibi Scheme 0.5.3:

```
(define-library (example hello)
    (export hello-world)
    (import (scheme base))
    (begin
      (define (hello-world) "hello, world"))) 

(import (scheme write)
        (example hello))
(write (hello-world))
```

Unfortunately when executed, it generates an error about an undefined variable:

```
$ chibi-scheme  hello.scm 
ERROR: undefined variable: hello-world
```

I must be making a simple mistake but don't see it. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you need a begin in the library

Comment: @RossLarson: I think the `begin` is part of the R7RS `define-library` form, and specifies the contents of the library.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - Right, the `begin` is part of the spec and is used both in the R7RS examples and by Chibi's libraries.

Comment: Indeed it is, I apologize. Now that I think, my experience is with r6rs libraries, just using (library ...) and rather limited. (good thing I didn't post that as an answer, haha)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple mistake - according to the [Module System](http://synthcode.com/scheme/chibi/#h2_ModuleSystem) section of the user guide, the file name must match the module name:

> The definition of the module (foo bar baz) is searched for in the file "foo/bar/baz.sld".

So in this case the above library definition needs to be added to `example/hello.sld` and the import section needs to be extracted into a new `.scm` file (or input on the REPL, etc).

Anyway, a trivial solution but maybe it will be of help to someone else out there...

Answer (score 2):

In general, R7RS doesn't define how to make libraries visible to a Scheme system, and the meaning of code that mixes define-library with other Scheme forms isn't defined.